SQL query takes a long time - Index Spool and a Key Lookup that I've removed
We're having performance issues with a specific query in the SQL Server database. I've checked the logs in Application Insights and this is the only query that occassionally takes a long time to execute.

Upon investigating the query execution plan, I noticed an Index Spool (Eager Spool) operation with a significant cost of 23.2%. There is a Key Lookup that I tried to resolve by creating the following non-clustered index, after which I reran the AzureMaintenanceScript that updates the statistics:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_GroupedLocationEmployee_TenantId_CanBuy_CanSell] ON [Settings].[GroupedLocationEmployee]
(
    [TenantId] ASC,
    [CanBuy] ASC,
    [CanSell] ASC
)
INCLUDE([GroupedLocationId],[EmployeeId]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_GroupedLocationEmployee_GroupedLocationId_EmployeeId_TenantId] ON [Settings].[GroupedLocationEmployee]
(
    [GroupedLocationId] ASC,
    [EmployeeId] ASC,
    TenantId ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

I've pulled the query from SSMS -> Top Resource Consuming Queries. There are two plans and the bad one is what's forced right now:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BywpXM6lR (Bad plan)
Here is the second one, which I believe is good:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HybZLfTxC
I'm not sure how to move forward with optimizing this query. Any ideas?
Edit:
Another one https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy525GagA that takes very long.
(@__ef_filter__p_2 bit,@__ef_filter__Id_3 uniqueidentifier,@__ef_filter__p_4 bit,@__ef_filter__Id_5 uniqueidentifier,@__ef_filter__p_12 bit,@__ef_filter__Id_13 uniqueidentifier,@__ef_filter__p_16 bit,@__ef_filter__Id_17 uniqueidentifier,@__ef_filter__p_18 bit,@__ef_filter__Id_19 uniqueidentifier,@__ef_filter__p_20 bit,@__ef_filter__Id_21 uniqueidentifier,@__ef_filter__p_0 bit,@__ef_filter__Id_1 uniqueidentifier,@__ef_filter__p_8 bit,@__ef_filter__Id_9 uniqueidentifier,@__ef_filter__p_10 bit,@__ef_filter__Id_11 uniqueidentifier,@__ef_filter__p_6 bit,@__ef_filter__Id_7 uniqueidentifier,@___userEmail_0 nvarchar(50),@__ef_filter__p_14 bit,@__ef_filter__Id_15 uniqueidentifier,@__endDate_1 datetime2(7),@__p_3 int,@__p_2 int)SELECT [t8].[Id], [t8].[CustomerFirstName], [t8].[CustomerLastName], [t8].[CustomerNumber], [t8].[CustomerId], [t8].[CreationDate], [t8].[UpdatedOn], [t8].[IsReal], [t8].[FuturesPrice], [t8].[IsSell], [t8].[MarketAccount], [t8].[WasAcknowledge], [t8].[PassFill], [t8].[IsGtc], [t8].[Expiration], [t8].[Lots], [t8].[WorkingLots], [t8].[ProductId], [t8].[InstrumentCode], [t8].[MarketPrice], [t8].[FuturesMonth], [t8].[MarketId], [t8].[AccountName], [t8].[InternalCode], [t8].[Source], [t8].[Type], [t8].[Event], [t8].[State]
FROM (
    SELECT [m].[Id], CASE
        WHEN ([t].[Id] IS NULL) OR ([t4].[Id] IS NULL) THEN COALESCE([t4].[FirstName], [t5].[FirstName])
        ELSE N''
    END AS [CustomerFirstName], CASE
        WHEN ([t].[Id] IS NULL) OR ([t4].[Id] IS NULL) THEN COALESCE([t4].[LastName], [t5].[LastName])
        ELSE N''
    END AS [CustomerLastName], CASE
        WHEN ([t].[Id] IS NULL) OR ([t4].[Id] IS NULL) THEN COALESCE([t4].[Number], [t5].[Number])
        ELSE N''
    END AS [CustomerNumber], CASE
        WHEN ([t].[Id] IS NULL) OR ([t4].[Id] IS NULL) THEN [t5].[Id]
        ELSE [t4].[Id]
    END AS [CustomerId], [m].[CreatedOn] AS [CreationDate], [m].[UpdatedOn], CAST(1 AS bit) AS [IsReal], [m].[FuturesPrice], [m].[IsSell], [m].[MarketAccount], [m].[WasAcknowledge], [m].[PassFill], [m].[IsGtc], [m].[Expiration], [m].[Lots], [m].[WorkingLots], [t7].[Id] AS [ProductId], [t7].[Code] AS [InstrumentCode], [m].[MarketPrice], [m].[FuturesMonth], CONVERT(nvarchar(max), [m].[MarketId]) AS [MarketId], CONVERT(nvarchar(max), [t3].[Name]) AS [AccountName], CONVERT(nvarchar(max), [m].[InternalCode]) AS [InternalCode], CASE
        WHEN [m].[Source] = N'Contract' THEN 0
        WHEN [m].[Source] = N'Accumulation' THEN 2
        WHEN [m].[Source] = N'Offer' THEN 1
        WHEN [m].[Source] = N'PreHedge' THEN 5
        ELSE 3
    END AS [Source], CASE
        WHEN [m].[Type] = N'Market' THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS [Type], CASE
        WHEN [m].[Event] = N'Creation' THEN 0
        WHEN [m].[Event] = N'Edition' THEN 2
        WHEN [m].[Event] = N'Cancelation' THEN 1
        WHEN [m].[Event] = N'Roll' THEN 3
        WHEN [m].[Event] = N'Book' THEN 4
        WHEN [m].[Event] = N'RollBack' THEN 5
        WHEN [m].[Event] = N'PartiallyFilled' THEN 6
        WHEN [m].[Event] = N'Filled' THEN 7
        ELSE 8
    END AS [Event], CASE
        WHEN [m].[State] = N'Ready' THEN 0
        WHEN [m].[State] = N'Denied' THEN 1
        WHEN [m].[State] = N'Pending' THEN 2
        WHEN [m].[State] = N'Working' THEN 3
        WHEN [m].[State] = N'PartiallyFilled' THEN 4
        WHEN [m].[State] = N'Filled' THEN 5
        WHEN [m].[State] = N'Canceled' THEN 6
        WHEN [m].[State] = N'Rejected' THEN 7
        ELSE 8
    END AS [State]
    FROM [Transactions].[MarketTransaction] AS [m]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[CashSettlement], [c].[ChildCount], [c].[ChildOffersCount], [c].[Comments], [c].[CommodityId], [c].[ContractTypeId], [c].[CreatedBy], [c].[CreatedOn], [c].[CropYear], [c].[CustomerId], [c].[DeliveryEndDate], [c].[DeliveryLocationId], [c].[DeliveryStartDate], [c].[DoNotHedge], [c].[EmployeeId], [c].[ErpMessage], [c].[ErpStatus], [c].[Event], [c].[Expiration], [c].[ExtendedContractTypeId], [c].[Fees1], [c].[Fees2], [c].[FreightPrice], [c].[FuturesMonth], [c].[FuturesPrice], [c].[GrossRemainingBalance], [c].[InternalCode], [c].[IsActive], [c].[IsAppliedLoad], [c].[IsDeliveryDatesCustom], [c].[IsSell], [c].[LastTransactionQuantity], [c].[LocationId], [c].[NetBasis], [c].[Number], [c].[OfferId], [c].[ParentId], [c].[PassFill], [c].[PostedBasis], [c].[Price], [c].[PushBasis], [c].[Quantity], [c].[RealCropYear], [c].[RegionId], [c].[RemainingBalance], [c].[RootParentId], [c].[SeqId], [c].[Source], [c].[TenantId], [c].[TheirContract], [c].[TransactionTypeId], [c].[UpdatedBy], [c].[UpdatedEmployeeId], [c].[UpdatedOn]
        FROM [Transactions].[Contract] AS [c]
        WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_2 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_3 = [c].[TenantId])
    ) AS [t] ON [m].[ContractId] = [t].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [o].[Id], [o].[CashSettlement], [o].[ChangeRemainingBalanceOnProcess], [o].[Comments], [o].[CommodityId], [o].[ContractParentId], [o].[ContractTypeId], [o].[CreatedBy], [o].[CreatedOn], [o].[CropYear], [o].[CustomerId], [o].[DeliveryEndDate], [o].[DeliveryLocationId], [o].[DeliveryStartDate], [o].[EmployeeId], [o].[Event], [o].[Expiration], [o].[Fees1], [o].[Fees2], [o].[FillCount], [o].[FreightPrice], [o].[FuturesMonth], [o].[FuturesPrice], [o].[Gtc], [o].[HasRejection], [o].[Instrument], [o].[InternalCode], [o].[IsActive], [o].[IsDeliveryDatesCustom], [o].[IsInternal], [o].[IsOrphan], [o].[IsSell], [o].[LocationId], [o].[NetBasis], [o].[Number], [o].[PostedBasis], [o].[Price], [o].[PushBasis], [o].[Quantity], [o].[RealCropYear], [o].[RegionId], [o].[RemainingBalance], [o].[RemainingBalanceOnProcess], [o].[TenantId], [o].[TheirContract], [o].[TransactionTypeId], [o].[UpdatedBy], [o].[UpdatedEmployeeId], [o].[UpdatedOn]
        FROM [Transactions].[Offer] AS [o]
        WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_4 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_5 = [o].[TenantId])
    ) AS [t0] ON [m].[OfferId] = [t0].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [h].[Id], [h].[Account], [h].[CreatedBy], [h].[CreatedOn], [h].[HedgeCustomer], [h].[HedgeLocation], [h].[IsActive], [h].[Name], [h].[TenantId], [h].[UpdatedBy], [h].[UpdatedOn]
        FROM [Settings].[HedgeAccount] AS [h]
        WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_12 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_13 = [h].[TenantId])
    ) AS [t3] ON [m].[MarketAccount] = [t3].[Account]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [c0].[Id], [c0].[City], [c0].[Country], [c0].[CreatedBy], [c0].[CreatedOn], [c0].[Email], [c0].[FirstName], [c0].[IsActive], [c0].[IsInSync], [c0].[IsMobileAppEnable], [c0].[LastName], [c0].[MobileAppLimit], [c0].[Number], [c0].[PhoneNumber], [c0].[State], [c0].[Street], [c0].[TenantId], [c0].[UpdatedBy], [c0].[UpdatedOn], [c0].[WorkPhoneNumber], [c0].[ZipCode]
        FROM [Settings].[Customer] AS [c0]
        WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_16 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_17 = [c0].[TenantId])
    ) AS [t4] ON [t].[CustomerId] = [t4].[Id]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [c1].[Id], [c1].[City], [c1].[Country], [c1].[CreatedBy], [c1].[CreatedOn], [c1].[Email], [c1].[FirstName], [c1].[IsActive], [c1].[IsInSync], [c1].[IsMobileAppEnable], [c1].[LastName], [c1].[MobileAppLimit], [c1].[Number], [c1].[PhoneNumber], [c1].[State], [c1].[Street], [c1].[TenantId], [c1].[UpdatedBy], [c1].[UpdatedOn], [c1].[WorkPhoneNumber], [c1].[ZipCode]
        FROM [Settings].[Customer] AS [c1]
        WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_16 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_17 = [c1].[TenantId])
    ) AS [t5] ON [t0].[CustomerId] = [t5].[Id]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [c2].[Id], [c2].[AutoHedge], [c2].[BasisControl], [c2].[CreatedBy], [c2].[CreatedOn], [c2].[CropEndDay], [c2].[CropEndMonth], [c2].[CropEndYear], [c2].[CropStartDay], [c2].[CropStartMonth], [c2].[CropStartYear], [c2].[IsActive], [c2].[IsInSync], [c2].[LotFactor], [c2].[Name], [c2].[Number], [c2].[NumberOfCropYears], [c2].[PriceControl], [c2].[ProductId], [c2].[TenantId], [c2].[UpdatedBy], [c2].[UpdatedOn]
        FROM [Settings].[Commodity] AS [c2]
        WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_18 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_19 = [c2].[TenantId])
    ) AS [t6] ON [m].[CommodityId] = [t6].[Id]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Code], [p].[CreatedBy], [p].[CreatedOn], [p].[Description], [p].[ExchangeSymbol], [p].[FutureMonths], [p].[IsActive], [p].[IsInSync], [p].[LimitOrderPrefix], [p].[MarketOrderPrefix], [p].[Number], [p].[TenantId], [p].[UpdatedBy], [p].[UpdatedOn]
        FROM [Settings].[Product] AS [p]
        WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_20 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_21 = [p].[TenantId])
    ) AS [t7] ON [t6].[ProductId] = [t7].[Id]
    WHERE ((@__ef_filter__p_0 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_1 = [m].[TenantId])) AND (([m].[IsActive] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([m].[Source] IN (N'ExternalFill', N'PreHedge') OR EXISTS (
        SELECT DISTINCT 1
        FROM [Settings].[GroupedLocationEmployee] AS [g]
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT [e].[Id], [e].[AlertSound], [e].[CreatedBy], [e].[CreatedOn], [e].[Email], [e].[FirstName], [e].[IsActive], [e].[IsInSync], [e].[LastName], [e].[Number], [e].[PhoneNumber], [e].[Role], [e].[Tag50], [e].[Tag50Account], [e].[TenantId], [e].[UpdatedBy], [e].[UpdatedOn]
            FROM [Settings].[Employee] AS [e]
            WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_8 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_9 = [e].[TenantId])
        ) AS [t1] ON [g].[EmployeeId] = [t1].[Id]
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT [g0].[Id], [g0].[ContractLocationId], [g0].[CreatedOn], [g0].[DestinationLocationId], [g0].[IsActive], [g0].[RegionId], [g0].[TenantId]
            FROM [Settings].[GroupedLocation] AS [g0]
            WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_10 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_11 = [g0].[TenantId])
        ) AS [t2] ON [g].[GroupedLocationId] = [t2].[Id]
        WHERE (((@__ef_filter__p_6 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_7 = [g].[TenantId])) AND ((([g].[CanBuy] = CAST(1 AS bit)) OR ([g].[CanSell] = CAST(1 AS bit))) AND ([t1].[Email] = @___userEmail_0))) AND ((((([t2].[DestinationLocationId] = [t].[DeliveryLocationId]) OR (([t2].[DestinationLocationId] IS NULL) AND ([t].[DeliveryLocationId] IS NULL))) AND (([t2].[ContractLocationId] = [t].[LocationId]) OR (([t2].[ContractLocationId] IS NULL) AND ([t].[LocationId] IS NULL)))) AND (([t2].[RegionId] = [t].[RegionId]) OR (([t2].[RegionId] IS NULL) AND ([t].[RegionId] IS NULL)))) OR (([t2].[DestinationLocationId] = [t0].[DeliveryLocationId]) OR (([t2].[DestinationLocationId] IS NULL) AND ([t0].[DeliveryLocationId] IS NULL)))))))
    UNION
    SELECT [o0].[Id], [t10].[FirstName] AS [CustomerFirstName], [t10].[LastName] AS [CustomerLastName], [t10].[Number] AS [CustomerNumber], [t10].[Id] AS [CustomerId], [o0].[CreatedOn] AS [CreationDate], [o0].[UpdatedOn], CAST(0 AS bit) AS [IsReal], COALESCE([t9].[FuturesPrice], 0.0) AS [FuturesPrice], CASE
        WHEN [t9].[IsSell] = CAST(0 AS bit) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
    END AS [IsSell], 0 AS [MarketAccount], CAST(0 AS bit) AS [WasAcknowledge], CAST(0 AS bit) AS [PassFill], [t9].[Gtc] AS [IsGtc], [t9].[Expiration], CAST(([t9].[Quantity] / CAST([t11].[LotFactor] AS decimal(18,2))) AS int) AS [Lots], 0 AS [WorkingLots], [t11].[ProductId], [t12].[Code] AS [InstrumentCode], [t9].[FreightPrice] AS [MarketPrice], [t9].[FuturesMonth], NULL AS [MarketId], NULL AS [AccountName], CONVERT(nvarchar(max), [t9].[InternalCode]) AS [InternalCode], 1 AS [Source], 1 AS [Type], CASE
        WHEN [o0].[Action] = N'Cancel' THEN 1
        WHEN [o0].[Action] = N'Add' THEN 0
        ELSE 2
    END AS [Event], 2 AS [State]
    FROM [Transactions].[OfferMonitoring] AS [o0]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [o1].[Id], [o1].[CashSettlement], [o1].[ChangeRemainingBalanceOnProcess], [o1].[Comments], [o1].[CommodityId], [o1].[ContractParentId], [o1].[ContractTypeId], [o1].[CreatedBy], [o1].[CreatedOn], [o1].[CropYear], [o1].[CustomerId], [o1].[DeliveryEndDate], [o1].[DeliveryLocationId], [o1].[DeliveryStartDate], [o1].[EmployeeId], [o1].[Event], [o1].[Expiration], [o1].[Fees1], [o1].[Fees2], [o1].[FillCount], [o1].[FreightPrice], [o1].[FuturesMonth], [o1].[FuturesPrice], [o1].[Gtc], [o1].[HasRejection], [o1].[Instrument], [o1].[InternalCode], [o1].[IsActive], [o1].[IsDeliveryDatesCustom], [o1].[IsInternal], [o1].[IsOrphan], [o1].[IsSell], [o1].[LocationId], [o1].[NetBasis], [o1].[Number], [o1].[PostedBasis], [o1].[Price], [o1].[PushBasis], [o1].[Quantity], [o1].[RealCropYear], [o1].[RegionId], [o1].[RemainingBalance], [o1].[RemainingBalanceOnProcess], [o1].[TenantId], [o1].[TheirContract], [o1].[TransactionTypeId], [o1].[UpdatedBy], [o1].[UpdatedEmployeeId], [o1].[UpdatedOn]
        FROM [Transactions].[Offer] AS [o1]
        WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_4 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_5 = [o1].[TenantId])
    ) AS [t9] ON [o0].[OfferId] = [t9].[Id]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [c3].[Id], [c3].[City], [c3].[Country], [c3].[CreatedBy], [c3].[CreatedOn], [c3].[Email], [c3].[FirstName], [c3].[IsActive], [c3].[IsInSync], [c3].[IsMobileAppEnable], [c3].[LastName], [c3].[MobileAppLimit], [c3].[Number], [c3].[PhoneNumber], [c3].[State], [c3].[Street], [c3].[TenantId], [c3].[UpdatedBy], [c3].[UpdatedOn], [c3].[WorkPhoneNumber], [c3].[ZipCode]
        FROM [Settings].[Customer] AS [c3]
        WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_16 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_17 = [c3].[TenantId])
    ) AS [t10] ON [t9].[CustomerId] = [t10].[Id]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [c4].[Id], [c4].[AutoHedge], [c4].[BasisControl], [c4].[CreatedBy], [c4].[CreatedOn], [c4].[CropEndDay], [c4].[CropEndMonth], [c4].[CropEndYear], [c4].[CropStartDay], [c4].[CropStartMonth], [c4].[CropStartYear], [c4].[IsActive], [c4].[IsInSync], [c4].[LotFactor], [c4].[Name], [c4].[Number], [c4].[NumberOfCropYears], [c4].[PriceControl], [c4].[ProductId], [c4].[TenantId], [c4].[UpdatedBy], [c4].[UpdatedOn]
        FROM [Settings].[Commodity] AS [c4]
        WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_18 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_19 = [c4].[TenantId])
    ) AS [t11] ON [t9].[CommodityId] = [t11].[Id]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [p0].[Id], [p0].[Code], [p0].[CreatedBy], [p0].[CreatedOn], [p0].[Description], [p0].[ExchangeSymbol], [p0].[FutureMonths], [p0].[IsActive], [p0].[IsInSync], [p0].[LimitOrderPrefix], [p0].[MarketOrderPrefix], [p0].[Number], [p0].[TenantId], [p0].[UpdatedBy], [p0].[UpdatedOn]
        FROM [Settings].[Product] AS [p0]
        WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_20 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_21 = [p0].[TenantId])
    ) AS [t12] ON [t11].[ProductId] = [t12].[Id]
    WHERE ((@__ef_filter__p_14 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_15 = [o0].[TenantId])) AND (([o0].[Action] = N'Add') AND EXISTS (
        SELECT DISTINCT 1
        FROM [Settings].[GroupedLocationEmployee] AS [g1]
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT [e0].[Id], [e0].[AlertSound], [e0].[CreatedBy], [e0].[CreatedOn], [e0].[Email], [e0].[FirstName], [e0].[IsActive], [e0].[IsInSync], [e0].[LastName], [e0].[Number], [e0].[PhoneNumber], [e0].[Role], [e0].[Tag50], [e0].[Tag50Account], [e0].[TenantId], [e0].[UpdatedBy], [e0].[UpdatedOn]
            FROM [Settings].[Employee] AS [e0]
            WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_8 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_9 = [e0].[TenantId])
        ) AS [t13] ON [g1].[EmployeeId] = [t13].[Id]
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT [g2].[Id], [g2].[ContractLocationId], [g2].[CreatedOn], [g2].[DestinationLocationId], [g2].[IsActive], [g2].[RegionId], [g2].[TenantId]
            FROM [Settings].[GroupedLocation] AS [g2]
            WHERE (@__ef_filter__p_10 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_11 = [g2].[TenantId])
        ) AS [t14] ON [g1].[GroupedLocationId] = [t14].[Id]
        WHERE (((@__ef_filter__p_6 = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND (@__ef_filter__Id_7 = [g1].[TenantId])) AND ((([g1].[CanBuy] = CAST(1 AS bit)) OR ([g1].[CanSell] = CAST(1 AS bit))) AND ([t13].[Email] = @___userEmail_0))) AND ([t14].[DestinationLocationId] = [t9].[DeliveryLocationId])))
) AS [t8]
WHERE CASE
    WHEN [t8].[UpdatedOn] IS NULL THEN CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(date, [t8].[CreationDate]) <= @__endDate_1 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
    END
    ELSE CASE
        WHEN CONVERT(date, [t8].[UpdatedOn]) <= @__endDate_1 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
    END
END = CAST(1 AS bit)
ORDER BY COALESCE([t8].[UpdatedOn], [t8].[CreationDate]) DESC
OFFSET @__p_2 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_3 ROWS ONLY


That looks like a horrible query, but with out context, about the tables and wanted result we can not tell if the index help or not

If you use .UseRelationalNulls() in your model builder you would probably simplify this significantly, but it could change the semantics. And in general it's not just about getting a Seek, it's about making sure that the data being read is exactly what you need and nothing more (so Number of Rows and Actual Number of Rows should be the same)
